# NetSuite beforeload cancel action

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a userevent beforeload that conditionally removes print buttons. If users are in the list view they are still able to print from that menu. So I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to either intercept the request and redirect or notify them, or even change which pdf template is used.

Here is my code snippet:

```
if (scriptContext.type === scriptContext.UserEventType.PRINT) {
                    if(status == 2){
                        log.debug({
                            title: 'Trying to Print Approved PO',
                            details: status
                        });
                        return true;
                    }
                    else{
                        log.debug({
                            title: 'Trying to Print UnApproved PO',
                            details: status
                        });
                        //code here to redirect users, notify them of issue or change to different pdf template
                        return false;
                    }


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

While not ideal, I just threw an error and didn't catch it.

```
throw 'This error is a result of trying to print a PO that has not been approved.';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add checkbox field on the UE beforeLoad event and set the value true/false if the user can/can't generate the pdf. Then control the new field on the freemarker AdvPDF and instead of print the content, you can show a message if the user can't generate the pdf.

```js
var field = objForm.addField({
  id: 'custpage_allow_access',
  type: serverWidget.FieldType.CHECKBOX,
  label: 'Allow access'
});

field.defaultValue = "F";

field.updateDisplayType({
  displayType: serverWidget.FieldDisplayType.HIDDEN
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I thought about this but we have quite a few templates and I was hoping to avoid adding logic to all of them and keep them as clean as possible.